# Manipulating CSVs in Unix - best native Unix tools to learn

Tags: awk, sed, perl, csv

I am new in the Unix environment. I am looking to learn manipulating CSV files (for example: adding new columns, getting values from one CSV by index and appending the value in a new CSV file etc.) in Unix. I am aware Python can be used, however the system restricts me from using Pandas, Numpy etc. I am looking to learn native Unix tools to parse and manipulate CSV files. I read awk, sed are okay for simpler CSV files but can get messy for complicated CSV files (but I would love your input). I am looking for some suggestions from the experts here about native Unix tools for CSV manipulation that won't require any kind of installation. What tools should I focus on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you parsing, is the parsing to be done as part of some existing software (written in _what_ language), and on what type of system are you parsing it? "Unix" does not come with any tools that natively knows about CSV. This is what packages provide. For example, the `csvkit` toolbox of Python utilities, other Python modules, and Perl with CSV parsing modules. You can parse comma-delimited data easily enough with `awk`, but CSV is not just comma-delimited data. It is unclear what you need, and answers will likely devolve into useless lists of "things I like". What is your actual issue?

Comment: ... also, if you have a system that does not have proper parsers, then get your admin to install them. Their job is to provide a system that is usable. If the say no, or if you have "rules", then there will be channels and procedures for you to use to get the proper prerequisites for getting your job done.

Comment: If all you have available are the mandatory POSIX tools (which includes awk but excludes perl, ruby, python, etc.) then see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk). There are no other mandatory POSIX tools that you should consider using to parse CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any "standard Unix tools" for CSV, not as standard as **awk**, **cut**, **grep**, **sed**, etc..., anyways.

- I mentioned GoCSV to you before, and it's still gets my highest recommendation.  It's fast, mostly streaming (designed for pipelines).  It was inspired by csvkit.
- csvkit is good, but I've had trouble installing it on an ARM based machine (Macbook Air w/M1 processor), and if numpy is an issue, that might disqualify csvkit as csvkit has a dependency on it.  If you check out [this doc](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html), you'll see other tools that inspired csvkit.  Some of those may be more standard on your system.

You mentioned scripting in Python yourself, but seem to think you need numpy or pandas.  You don't.  They can make things easy and your code really short, but you can do everything you need for reading, sorting, indexing, filtering, and writing CSVs with Python's own [**csv** module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).  That official documentation is a good reference, but for starters I recommend Python for Beginner's, [CSV Files](https://python-adv-web-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csv.html). I've also written my own primer for CSVs in Python, [Welcome to CSV w/Python!](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/618d3348855a31b7dd90e221f4e0dba7), based on reading a lot Python-CSV code from people struggling on StackOverflow.

Comment: After reading, I decided to go with Python as you said. I wish I could use GoCSV, however external packages are not allowed to be installed in the system I use.

Answer (score 1):

The best Unix tools CSV aware for me is Miller:

https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/